# how can I insert multiple records into sqlite table at once android?

Tags: java, android, xml, database, sqlite

my app contain sqlite db , sometimes it needs to insert lots of rows,  Is there a way to insert multiple rows into sqlite table at once?
I saw some methods using bulk insert but I didn't know how to use these methods in the entry activity
I'm using editTexts  for insertion could You please help me I'm desperate !! :( thanks in return.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert multiple records using Batch operation. or you can use Sqlite with Content provider which has some built in methods for it

```
sqlDb.beginTransaction();

    for (ContentValues cv : values) {
        sqlDb.insert(
                getTableName(ContentDescriptor.URI_MATCHER.match(uri), uri),
                null, cv);
    }

    sqlDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    sqlDb.endTransaction();
```

Comment: ok but how can i use it in the entry activity, for example edittext for the name it takes one name , what should I do how to add multiple names ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the **multiple insertions in the query itself** like this:

INSERT INTO table_name(id,name,address) VALUES
(1, "Test","Address1"),
(2, "Test","Address2"),
(3, "Test","Address3")

and use this query with `db.execSql`